# Escaping MySQL LOAD DATA INFILE command

Tags: python, mysql, csv

I want to escape this command in Python 3.6, as I want to use it to run it through a bulk of csv files.

```
for filename in glob.glob(CSV_FOLDER_LOCATION + "/*.csv"):
    # Adds quotes to filename because of the problem caused by spaces in path names
    quoted_filename = '"' + filename + '"'
    os.system(MYSQL_LOCATION + r" -u root LOAD DATA INFILE " + quoted_filename + " INTO TABLE " + TABLE_NAME +
              r" CHARACTER SET ascii FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '/n' IGNORE 1 LINES")
```

The comma shows up as whitespace. This is the output:

```
C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/bin/mysql.exe -u root LOAD DATA INFILE "C:/prog/csv/CSVFiles\CC19711977ZWEIG-ZZ.csv" INTO TABLE vcc2.tmp_cards CHARACTER SET ascii FIELDS TERMINATED BY   ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '/n' IGNORE 1 LINES
```

What is the correct way to escape that string?

Edit: Added image for clarification:
[image]

Maybe I'm really thick and missing something obvious, but how can I "raw string" it C-style?

Comment: Why are you doing this via `os.system()`?

Comment: Please give me your suggestion!

Comment: Well there is a [python library made for interacting with MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/) so I would probably use that.

Comment: It has to be standalone, this is just a very simple script needed to import all CSV files in a folder into MySQL

Comment: are you looking for `shlex.quote`?

Comment: Not exactly, I added an image to the OP to hopefully better explain. I am getting syntax error for unclosed quote, but MySQL takes as "argument" a single quote like that, so I cannot just close it

Answer (score 1):

Escaped it this way:

```
os.system(
            r"LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE " + '"' + CSV_FOLDER_LOCATION + '/' + filename + '"' + " INTO TABLE " + TABLE_NAME +
            r' CHARACTER SET ascii FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' + '\',\'' + ' ENCLOSED BY ' + '\'"\'' +
            ' LINES TERMINATED BY ' + '\'\\n\'' + ' IGNORE 1 LINES')
```